# AS3 - removeEventListener(ADDED_TO_STAGE)

Tags: actionscript-3, events, actionscript, event-handling

I'm having some problems with trying to remove `Event.ADD_TO_STAGE` basically in this game ive developed once the lives is less than or equal to zero the game will end and switch to the game over screen however when I do that it kicks back with this error.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.   
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
at States/changeState()
at AvoiderGame/onTick()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

This then turns into..

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Enemy/StayOnScreen()
at AvoiderGame/onTick()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I'm not entirely sure why - could anyone clarify why it does and how I could fix it?

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import com.freeactionscript.CollisionTest;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip
{
    var theCallBackFunction:Function;

    public static var enemyArray:Array;
    public var enemy:Enemy
    public var Background:gameBackground;
    public var Lives:Number = 3;

    public var avatar:Avatar;
    public var gameTimer:Timer;

    private var _collisionTest:CollisionTest;
    private var numStars:int = 80;

    private var fireTimer:Timer; //causes delay between fires
    private var canFire:Boolean = true; //can you fire a laser

    public function AvoiderGame(callBack)
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        theCallBackFunction = callBack;
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        Background = new gameBackground();
        addChild(Background);

        enemyArray = new Array();

        avatar = new Avatar(stage);
        addChild(avatar);

        avatar.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        avatar.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

        _collisionTest = new CollisionTest();

        gameTimer = new Timer(25);
        gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
        gameTimer.start();

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), 1);
        }

        fireTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
        fireTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fireTimerHandler, false, 0, true);
        fireTimer.start();
    }

    public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void 
    {

        if (Math.random() < 0.1)
        {
            trace('array length: ', AvoiderGame.enemyArray.length);
            enemy = new Enemy(Math.round(1 + (500 - 1) * Math.random()), - 28, stage);
            enemyArray.push(enemy);
            addChild(enemy);
            enemy.gotoAndStop("Enemy" + Math.round(1 + (5 - 1) * Math.random()))
        }

        canFire = avatar.UpdateAvatar(canFire);
        if (canFire == false)
        {
            fireTimer.start();
        }
        avatar.StayOnScreen();

        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemyArray)
        {
            enemy.moveDown();
            enemy.StayOnScreen();
            if (_collisionTest.complex(enemy, avatar)) 
            {
                gameTimer.stop();
                for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemyArray)
                {
                    for(var i:int = 0; i < enemyArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        removeChild(enemyArray[i]);
                        enemyArray.splice(i, 1); //remove the i'th element as i'th element is the enemy containing the ID of hit enemy
                    }
                }
                Lives--;
                trace('lives: ', Lives);
                gameTimer.start();
            }
        }

        if (Lives == 0)
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
            theCallBackFunction(this, "over");
        }
    }
    private function fireTimerHandler(e:TimerEvent) : void
    {
        //timer ran, we can fire again.
        canFire = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where in onTick - you got the error? Also in handler for ADDED_TO_STAGE you should unregister it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//use weak references so the listener can be disposed of if necessary

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init, false, 0, true);

private function init(e:Event):void {

//remove this now as we have added the object to the stage
this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

//add a new listener that will fire when the object is removed from stage
this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, reset, false, 0, true);
```

...

```
private function reset(e:Event):void {

//this function is called when the object has been removed from the stage
this.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, reset);

//now make sure all timers and stopped and nulled if required
//as well as all objects removed from stage and nulled if required. e.g.

fireTimer.stop();
fireTimer = null;

enemyArray = [];
enemyArray = null;

enemy

removeChild(Background);
Background = null;

removeChild(avatar);
avatar = null;

gameTimer.stop();
gameTimer = null;

_collisionTest = null;

}
```

//NB. You are adding stars to the stage and have no way of referencing them to remove them.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
{
   stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), 1);
}
```

//you might want to add them to an array so you can remove them.

```
var starArray = [];

for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
{
   var newStar:Star = new Star(stage);
   stage.addChildAt(newStar, 1);
   starArray.push(newStar);
}
```

Then to remove them:

```
for (var i:int = starArray.length; i > 0; i--)
{

   stage.removeChild(starArray[starArray.length-1]);

}
starArray = [];
starArray = null;
```

Comment: Error: Error #2094: Event dispatch recursion overflow.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at States/changeState()
 at AvoiderGame/reset()
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at States/changeState()
 at AvoiderGame/onTick()
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

This is what I keep getting ever since I added in the reset functiom.

Comment: As part of a general debugging procedure, if a bug is not immediately obvious, try commenting everything out, then uncomment and test each line of chunk of code to see when the error appears. Regarding your error, try stopping both timers before doing anything else.